# Saving cart object during one session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, shopping-cart

I'm making an online store just to improve rails skills. I want to let unauthorized user add items to cart. For that I should somehow store cart object and items added to it in session or somewhere else. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a Hash to the users session (which also creates if he isnt logged in yet).

```
session[:cart] = Array.new if !session[:cart]
```

And then when he adds an Object to the cart you can add a hash to the array in the session like this.

```
session[:cart] << hash.new(:product_id => <id>, :quantity => 1337)
```

Of cause you could also create a Model `Cart`and write the `cart_id` to the session like this.

```
session[:cart_id] = <cart_id>
```

But the disadvantage using this method (which is for usual the quit better way) that you cant destroy the entry till the session is destroyed and so you might get some trouble with all the old carts.